# Google Maps SDK [Android] : How to get/set MaxIntensity for heatmap?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I'm in the process of currently writing a heat map application that is using Google Maps SDK with dynamic data.

The heat map intensity is based on the interpolation of the gradient with the relative maximum of the data [*]

For the dynamic data, I know the upper and lower bounds of the values that will arrive but I do not know when they will occur.

For example, 1 is the lowest value possible and 10 is the highest possible value.

I could receive data as {1,1,2,4,5} and then the next data arrival could make the data {1,1,2,4,5,10}. Because the heat map intensity is relative , this results in the gradient/heatmap changing colour (because it is relative).

For data instance of {1,1,2,4,5}. The value 5 would be represented as the highest possible intensity whereas I want it to be in relation to the absolute possible intensity (10).

I have tried to add pairs of LatLng nearby for the upper and lower bounds of data, but this affects the opacity of data as it tends to be based upon pixel density. And the MaxIntensity functionality is lacking from the android SDK of google maps.

```
List<WeightedLatLng> list = new ArrayList<WeightedLatLng>();
// ... do stuff to add all the formatted data to list
// 10 represents total maximum, add this onto end of data list for scaling
list.add(new WeightedLatLng( new LatLng(0,0),10));
mProvider = new HeatmapTileProvider.Builder().weightedData(list).gradient(gradient).build();
// Add a tile overlay to the map, using the heat map tile provider.
overlay = mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().tileProvider(mProvider));
```

[*] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/utility/heatmap

[**] https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/heatmaplayer

Comment: Seems as though you'd have to change the gradient to achieve the desired effect updated as the current data maximum approaches 10.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a noob but maybe it will help.

I've added to the data list a WeightedLatLng in (85,0) with the max intensity, in your case 10. So this point won't be visible and the others will be based on it.

```
list.add(new WeightedLatLng(new LatLng(85,0),10));
```

It worked for me but I don't know if it's universal. If there are cleaner solutions I'm interested too.

**Edit:** I think it's important to notice that this solution removes relativity between intensities only if clusters intensities are less than your max intensity.

For exemple if your max intensity is 10 and you have 3 points with intensity 4 in the same place, the cluster intensity will be 3*4=12 and will take over the max intensity.

To reformulate, if there are clusters intensities greater than your max intensity colors will be relative to the greater cluster intensity (your 10 will glow down). Otherwise it will be displayed all as you want it to be.